# i m using openxml to download database data to a excel file but After the program run file not download in the chrome

Tags: reactjs, .net

```
    [HttpGet("download")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadTableData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        // Get the table data for the specified date range
        var data = await _grievanceContext.GrievanceResponses.Where(d => d.CreatedDate.Date >= startDate && d.CreatedDate.Date <= endDate).ToListAsync();

        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("data");
            var currentRow = 1;
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "Grievance Number";
            worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = "Response";

            foreach (var user in data)
            {
                currentRow++;
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = user.GrieNo;
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = user.Response;
            }

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                stream.Position = 0; // reset the stream position to the beginning
                var content = stream.ToArray();
                return File(
                    content,
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                    "Grievance.xlsx"
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to download exce file named Grievance.xlxs